# Prepared statements: while loop inside while loop. How to display ordered files in groups?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is the code of a website of a non-profit organization that sponsors children in a situation of need; The sponsor can login to his/her user account and every three months see a series of files of his godchild (photos, letters, etc.) that can download.

This code should select the available files registered in a table named 'files' and show the result sorted by its corresponding period, are four periods of three months.

Example:

First quarter of 2016

Archive A1 ::: Archive B1 ::: Archive C1

Second quarter of 2016

Archive A2 ::: Archive B2 ::: Archive C2

Etc.

The problem so far has been that the page shows either the ordered periods if i remove the '$file statement' from 'while ( $updates -> fetch())', or shows all the files of all periods together with the '$file statement' whitout the '$updates statement'.

Can somebody help me?

```
<?php
...

        // This relate the file with its user.
        $FileCode = $_SESSION["Card"];

        echo '
            <div class="contentLogIn">
                <div class="ctlg-ins">
                    <p class="startText">My files</p>
                </div>
        ';


        // I use SELECT DISTINCT because in the table 'files' multiple values can have the same period but i only want to know if the period have values not how much.

        $updates = $db->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT Trimester, Quarter, Year FROM files WHERE FileCode=? ORDER BY Year DESC, Quarter DESC, Trimester DESC");
        if ($updates === FALSE) {trigger_error($db->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);}
        $updates->bind_param("s", $FileCode);
        $updates->execute();
        $updates->bind_result( $Trimester, $Quarter, $Year );
        while ( $updates->fetch() ) {


            // For every single period shows its title.

            if ( isset($Year, $Quarter) ) {
                $FilesDate = $Trimester . "&nbsp;quarter&nbsp;of&nbsp;" . $Year; // Output example: *First quarter of 2016*
            } else {
                $FilesDate = "There's no available files.";
            }
            echo '
                    <div class="W100">
                        <p class="startTextDesc">' . $FilesDate . '</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="A12">
            ';


            $files = $db->prepare("SELECT Type, Class, SRC FROM files WHERE FileCode=? AND Quarter=? AND Year=?");
            if ($files === FALSE) { trigger_error($db->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR); }
            $files->bind_param("sss", $FileCode, $Quarter, $Year);
            $files->execute();
            $files->bind_result($Type, $Class, $SRC);
            while ( $files->fetch() ) {


                // This is the file that it is supposed to be displayed under its period title - like the example i post before.

                echo '
                        <div class="FileCont  CustomPointer">
                            <form method="POST" action="/php/File.Download.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="fileButton" id="fileButton" value="' . $SRC . '">
                                <button type="submit" class="buttonFile-download">
                                    <div class="CustomPointer">
                                        <p style="...">' . $Type . '</p>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                ';
            }
            $files->free_result();
            echo '
                    </div>
            ';
        }
        $updates->free_result();
        echo '
            </div>
        ';
...
?>
```

Comment: Prepare once, execute multiple times. Or, just do a single DB query and keep track of your different periods with variables.

Comment: It's true, the '$files statement' is executing multiple times but i do it this way just for post it here more 'readable', however it doesn't work either.

Comment: I think your schema needs redesigning. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work; you use a variable (`$CurrentFilesDate`) to keep track of the period, and when you see it changes, you put a new header in.

```
$CurrentFilesDate = "";
$updates = $db->prepare("SELECT Trimester, Quarter, Year, Type, Class, SRC FROM files WHERE FileCode=? ORDER BY Year DESC, Quarter DESC, Trimester DESC");
if ($updates === FALSE) {
    trigger_error($db->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$updates->bind_param("s", $FileCode);
$updates->execute();
$updates->bind_result( $Trimester, $Quarter, $Year, $Type, $Class, $SRC );
while ( $updates->fetch() ) {
    $FilesDate = $Trimester . "&nbsp;quarter&nbsp;of&nbsp;" . $Year;
    if ($FilesDate != $CurrentFilesDate) {
        if (!empty($CurrentFilesDate)) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '
                <div class="W100">
                    <p class="startTextDesc">' . $FilesDate . '</p>
                </div>
                <div class="A12">
        ';
        $CurrentFilesDate = $FilesDate;
    }
    echo '
            <div class="FileCont  CustomPointer">
                <form method="POST" action="/php/File.Download.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="fileButton" id="fileButton" value="' . $SRC . '">
                    <button type="submit" class="buttonFile-download">
                        <div class="CustomPointer">
                            <p style="...">' . $Type . '</p>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
    ';
}
echo '</div>';
```

This code is very ugly though, you should be separating your PHP and HTML. I recommend using the DB loop to build an array in the structure you need, and then loop through it in an HTML template that contains only simple `echo` statements.